# Spring Cloud Gateway chaining nested Mono

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a web app (Spring Cloud Gateway with Project Reactor) where I have to logout (send another http request) when something goes wrong and set 401 to the main response. The problem is when I execute another request in `onErrorResume` block, the root response seems to ignore `finishWithStatus()` logic entirely and returns 200.

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return  someFunctionWhichReturnsMono()
                .flatMap(chain::filter)
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    log.error("Unexpected Filter Error, logging out user", e);

                    // A. this doesn't set 401, seems like ignoring finishWithStatus(..) 
                    // called inside this method in onErrorResume block
                    return logout(exchange);  

                    // B. this works fine and I get 401 as a response
                    // return finishWithStatus(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                });
    }

    protected Mono<Void> finishWithStatus(ServerWebExchange exchange, HttpStatus status) {
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(status);
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }

    protected void logout(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        webClient
                .post()
                .uri(....)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Void.class)
                .doOnSuccess(any -> {
                    log.info("Successfully logged out user");
                })
                .then(finishWithStatus(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    log.error("Failed to logout user", e);
                    //the following line has no effect when error happens
                    return finishWithStatus(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                });
    }
```

Could somebody explain why is that despite I return Mono in both cases. However, in case `A` I have nested `onErrorResume` (at `onErrorResume` of the "root" `Mono` I create another `Mono` with its own `onErrorResume`).

I feel I miss something fundamental like I need to "join" two `Mono`s or say bubble up some `Mono.error` from the deepest `onErrorResume` to the top one?

What would be a generic approach to handle nested errors (like the case above when on an error you have to send another request which in turn might end up with an error).

I would greatly appreciate any advice or sample on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamental rule in reactive programming: Nothing happens until you **subscribe**

`finishWithStatus()` works because you are passing the publisher value to the next filter by returning `Mono<Void>` type.

You are making chain of reactive operators in `logout()` method but never subscribing or passing the publisher to the next filter. Therefore nothing happens even if you call this method

Another point is you can't return `logout()` method in `filter()` method since the return type for `filter()` is `Mono<Void>` not `void`.

You should change the return type for `logout()` method:

```
protected Mono<Void> logout(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .uri(...)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Void.class)
            .doOnSuccess(any -> {
                log.info("Successfully logged out user");
            })
            .then(finishWithStatus(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                log.error("Failed to logout user", e);
                return finishWithStatus(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            });
}
```